# Angular2: No Provider for <custom service>

Tags: angular

I had working code with alpha44 but the upgrade to beta is defeating me. I get this error:

```
EXCEPTION: No provider for e! (HomeCmp -> RestosSvc -> e)
```

I have include RestosSvc in my bootstrap, and the file can be found. This is part of my HomeCmp

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

import { Resto, RestosSvc } from '../../services/RestosSvc';


@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './components/home/home.html',
  styleUrls: ['./components/home/home.css'],
  directives: [FiltersCmp, ListCmp, MapCmp],
  providers: [RestosSvc]
})
export class HomeCmp {
  recommendations: Array<Resto> = [];
  presetCrits: Object;
  selectedResto: number = -1;
  top5: boolean;

  constructor(public restos: RestosSvc, urlCrits: RouteParams, public router: Router) {
```

And here is the RestoSvc

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class RestosSvc {
    http: Http;

    constructor(http:Http) {
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How does your RestosService look like?

Comment: @EricMartinez added it now

Comment: Simon, did you add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in your bootstrap, right? By the way, use the `dev` bundles to get the full error message, that will help you to debug.

Comment: I'm using https://gitter.im/mgechev/angular2-seed whihc has been configured with min.js, but adding HTTP_PROVIDERS seems to have moved me on to my next problem, so thanks

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same issue because we had mangle set to true during minification. The no provider for `e!` gave one of my colleagues a hint that this might be an issue with minification. Check your minified files and make sure that you use the ones that were generated with mangle set to false. This is an ongoing issue and is scheduled to be fixed in a couple of weeks

More info here: 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7306
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/262